# How to loop through controls within a gridview and store their values in an array?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

please excuse this potentially long post as I feel like most of the information I will add below is necessary. As the title states I am trying to loop through a collection of controls that are within a gridview on my page (there are 2 gridviews actually, but they are identical in behavior) and store the values of some of these controls in an array that I can use to perform other functions.

To start I have added the code for the gridview below.

```
<asp:Panel ID="gridPNL1" runat="server">

    Repair / Labor<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbAddRepair" Text="Add New Repair / Labor" CommandName="AddLabor" OnClick="AddObject_Click" Enabled="false" style="margin-left:20px" Visible="false" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
        EmptyDataText="No Claimed Labor" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="RecID"
        ShowFooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" Width="95%">
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEquipmentNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID"
            DataTextField="EquipmentPart" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px"
            Style="margin-left: 70px;" > <%-- Removed the OnSelectedIndexChanged (add if needed) --%>
            <asp:ListItem Value ="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRepair" DataValueField="RecID"
            DataTextField="Description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="220px"  Height="20px" AutoPostBack="true"
            style="" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRepairNew_SelectedIndexChanged"
            OnDataBinding="ddlRepairNew_DataBinding">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
<%--        <asp:textbox ID="txtDescOther" runat="server" Width="235px" Visible="false" />--%>
        <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="txtRepairHoursNew" Width="95px" style="margin-left: 68px"/>
        <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRepairHoursAllowed"></asp:Label>--%>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidAllowedRepairHoursNew" />
<%--        <asp:textbox ID="txtAllowedHoursNew" runat="server" Width="90px"/>--%>
        <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairCostNew" runat="server" Width="95px" ReadOnly="True"/>
        <asp:textbox ID="txtLineTotalNew" runat="server" Width="95px" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxNew" runat="server" Width="95px" text="0"/>
        <asp:Button ID="InsertDetail" runat="server" CommandName="InsertDetail" Height="25px" Text="Add Detail" Width="85px" />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" footertext="Add -->" ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderStyle-Width="70px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecID" HeaderText="RecID" SortExpression="RecID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Equipment / Repair / Labor Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRepairEquipmentType" Text='<%# Bind("EquipmentType") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" Width="220px" />
                    <asp:label ID="lblRepairType" Text='<%# Bind("RepairType") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" Width="220px"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEquipmentEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="EquipmentPart" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("EquipmentID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRepair" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="Description" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("RepairID")%>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="true" Width="220px" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRepairEdit_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEquipmentInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="EquipmentPart" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 29px" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRepair" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="Description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" autopostback="true" Width="220px" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRepairInsert_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBinding="ddlRepairInsert_DataBinding">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Repair Hours Requested" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:label ID="lblRepairHours" Text='<%# Bind("RepairHours")%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairHoursEdit" Text='<%# Bind("RepairHours")%>' runat="server" Width="95px" />
                        <%--<asp:Label ID="lblRepairHoursEdit" runat="server"></asp:Label>--%>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidAllowedRepairHoursEdit" Value='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairHoursInsert" runat="server" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
                <%--<center><asp:Label ID="lblRepairHoursInsert" runat="server"></asp:Label></center>--%>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidAllowedRepairHoursInsert" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Repair Hours Approved" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:label ID="lblAllowedHours" Text='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' runat="server" Width="50px"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:textbox ID="txtAllowedHoursEdit" Text='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' Enabled="true" runat="server" Width="50px"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:textbox ID="txtAllowedHoursInsert" Text='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' runat="server" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>--%>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Repair Cost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblRepairCost" Text='<%# Bind("RepairCost", "{0:C}") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairCostEdit" Text='<%# Bind("RepairCost") %>' runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="95px"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairCostInsert" Text='<%# Bind("RepairCost") %>' runat="server" ReadOnly="True" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Repair Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblRepairTotal" Text='<%# Bind("LaborRequested", "{0:C}")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairTotalEdit" Text='<%# Bind("LaborRequested")%>' Enabled="false" runat="server" Width="95px"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairTotalInsert" Text='<%# Bind("LaborRequested") %>' runat="server" Enabled="false" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbTaxTotal" Text='<%# Bind("Tax", "{0:C}")%>' runat="server" CommandArgument="Repair" OnClick="lblTaxTotal_Click" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairGST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("GST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairPST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("PST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairQST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("QST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairHST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("HST")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="lblTaxTotalEdit" Text='<%# Bind("Tax")%>' Enabled="true" runat="server" Width="95px"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxTotalInsert" runat="server" Enabled="true" text="0" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert New" HeaderStyle-Width="85px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" Text="" runat="server" Width="85px"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Insert" runat="server" CommandName="InsertNewDetail" Height="22px" Text="Insert" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" />
        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblErrorRepair" ForeColor="Red"  />
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

What I am trying to do with the gridview above is loop through some specific controls on the gridview and store their values in an array. Essentially how this gridview works is the user will enter information into a series of drop down lists and textboxes, as seen above, when the user hits the button at the end of the row (labeled "InsertDetail" and "Insert" respectively, it takes the data from the drop down list and textboxes and stores it in the labels (also above) for simpler display (this goes on for however many items the user needs to enter (usually around 2 - 5 items total)).  I need a way to loop through the values in however many iterations of "lblRepairEquipmentType" there are at the time the user hits any of the "insert" buttons and store the value of each iteration of "lblRepairEquipmentType" in an array so that I can use that array to perform other procedures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if there is something else I can try that would be better, either efficiency wise or just for best practices I would appreciate and welcome any  constructive criticism.  Thank you all for your patience and willingness to help.

Comment: So, will freely admit I could be thinking this in the complete wrong way.  Typically you are orders of magnitude much better off iterating over the DataSource you have your GridView bound to.  Trying to do this type of thing via UI controls can a) make some validation difficult b) produce unwanted visuals (flickers etc) c) a whole heap more code to maintain.  IMO, if unless you've got a real good reason, leave the UI layer for what the UI layer does best and do any data process on the actual data

Comment: Hey @Hursey,  thanks for the response.  Honestly, you may have solved my problem. I did not think to simply use the data that is stored in my db from these controls.  I am somewhat new to programming and I can say itll take a little bit of time for me to figure out where to pull the data from and reconfigure what I was going to do with it, but I wanna say this might be the answer I was looking for. I'll keep this post updated if this is the solution I was looking for!